# Continuous Dice rolls

Tags: probability, dice

A dice is being rolled continuously. Suppose you roll a 3 ( or any number ). What is the probability that you will get the next "3" *exactly* after **n** rolls?

Comment: I suspect you mean "A die is being rolled continually".

Comment: You are right.. I do mean continually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will interpret "after $n$ rolls" as meaning that we want the probability that our next $n-1$ rolls do not yield a $3$, but the $n$-th roll does give a $3$..

The probability of a non-$3$ on any toss is $\frac{5}{6}$.  So the probability of $n-1$ consecutive non-$3$'s followed by a $3$ is
$$\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{6}.$$

The reason that we simply multiply is that the results on successive tosses of the die are **independent**.  The die does not remember what results it has come up with in the past.

We can also get the result by using a **counting** argument. Imagine tossing a die $n$ times, and recording the results. So a record of $4$ tosses might read $4,5,4,1$.

There are $6^n$ possible records of the results of $n$ tosses, all **equally likely**.  There are $5^{n-1}$ records in which the first $n-1$ results are a non-$3$ and the last result is a $3$. So our probability is
$$\frac{5^{n-1}}{6^n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you **do** roll a $3$, then there would be a $1\over 6$ chance of rolling another $3$.  So, for the next two rolls after rolling just once, if you roll two more times, then there will be a $1\over 36$ chance of rolling two $3$s.  Here's a thing to help: Rolls to Get the Number | Chance the Number Will Appear Again Those Rolls$$2|{1\over6}$$$$3|{1\over 36}$$$$4|{1\over 216}$$$$5|{1\over1,296}$$

So, after one roll, the chance starts at the second roll and then multiplies by $1\over 6$ from the beginning as you go.  This works for any number on a six-sided die.